# Difference Value of the Specific heats at constant Pressure and Temperature of Real Gases

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

As in ideal gases, we can have the equation of $C_p=C_v+R$, or to be precise, the difference of the Specific heats of ideal gases at constant pressure and volume is the universal gas constant. But, we know, when the gas follows the Van der Waal's equation of $(p+\frac {a}{v^2})(v-b)=R$,then what will be the equation for $C_p-C_v$? Will the value decrease or increase? 
Please show the derivation of the equation in details, since I'm only a student! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at wikipedia, article "Relations between heat capacities" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities). There you will have a complete answer.

Comment: I don't get my answer in the wiki article, that's why I questioned it here

Comment: Well, you use the very first equation on the wikipedia article and evaluate the right hand side using the equation of state. That should work.